# TCL - Insert a row in a CSV file

Tags: csv, insert, tcl, row, edit

If anyone can help I would be extreemly greatful.

Using Tcl scripting I would like to insert a row in a csv file when the StringId increases. The oringinal data is as follows:

StringId,X,Y,Z,Pit,Cutback,Dump,RoadType,Stage,Description
1,4502.99062478626,11700.2712789007,1351.70766376371,Main,m12,,Ramp,,
1,4516.27744755097,11659.2215117983,1355.04407601514,Main,m12,,Ramp,,
2,4573.88,11115.096,1349.655,Main,m11,,Surface,,
2,4579.091,11005.027,1340.086,Main,m11,,Surface,,
3,4590.818,10957.154,1335.894,Main,m11,,Surface,,
3,4624.94,10868.638,1327.38,Main,m11,,Surface,,
4,4672.865,10803.07,1320,Main,m11,,Surface,,
4,4720.17,10757.545,1320.894,Main,m11,,Surface,,

I would like to change it to the following by inserting the 0,0,0,0 in a new row:

StringId,X,Y,Z,Pit,Cutback,Dump,RoadType,Stage,Description
1,4502.99062478626,11700.2712789007,1351.70766376371,Main,m12,,Ramp,,
1,4516.27744755097,11659.2215117983,1355.04407601514,Main,m12,,Ramp,,

0,0,0,0,

2,4573.88,11115.096,1349.655,Main,m11,,Surface,,
2,4579.091,11005.027,1340.086,Main,m11,,Surface,,

0,0,0,0

3,4590.818,10957.154,1335.894,Main,m11,,Surface,,
3,4624.94,10868.638,1327.38,Main,m11,,Surface,,

0,0,0,0,

4,4672.865,10803.07,1320,Main,m11,,Surface,,
4,4720.17,10757.545,1320.894,Main,m11,,Surface,,

Comment: What is the criteria for inserting the new row? Is it after the stringId field changes?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, we don't need to fully parse the file. Instead, we can get the first column with `lindex [split $line ","] 0` and leave the rest as unparsed. The only other trick is that we need to handle the column names as their own special thing, reading them before we suck in the rest of the data.

```
set f [open $inFilename]
set columnNames [gets $f]
set data [split [read $f] "\n"]
close $f

# In theory, we should check which column is StringId with [lsearch],
# but I hard code it to 0 for convenience

set f [open $outFilename w]
puts $f $columnNames
foreach line $data {
    set id [lindex [split $line ","] 0]
    # If we've changed the current ID, print the stuff to insert
    if {[info exist current] && $current != $id} {
        puts $f "\n0,0,0,0,\n"
    }
    # Remember the current ID
    set current $id
    puts $f $line
}
close $f
```

Comment: You might need to add some code to skip a blank line at the end. `[string trimright [read $f] "\n"]` would do it.

Comment: Or simply use `[read -nonewline $f]`

Comment: I always forget that option!

Comment: @ Donal Fellow
Thank you all so much for this. I dont know too much about this scripting but this has done exactly what i needed.